# Creating new variable by aggregation in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty new to python and pandas, and know only the basics. Nowadays I'm conducting a research and I need your kind help.

Let’s say I have data on births, containing 2 variables: Date and Country.

```
Date    Country
1.1.20  USA
1.1.20  USA
1.1.20  Italy
1.1.20  England
2.1.20  Italy
2.1.20  Italy
3.1.20  USA
3.1.20  USA
```

Now I want to create a third variable, let’s call him ‘Births’, which contains the number of births in country at a date. In other words, I want to stick to just one row for each date+country combination by aggregating the number of countries in each date, so I end up with something like this:

```
Date    Country Births
1.1.20  USA     2
1.1.20  Italy   1
1.1.20  England 1
2.1.20  Italy   2
3.1.20  USA     2
```

I’ve tried many things, but nothing seemed to work. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Eran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use the [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html#groupby) method of your DataFrame, then use the [`size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size) method to count the number of individuals in each group :

```
df.groupby(by=['Date', 'Country']).size().reset_index(name='Births')
```

Output:

```
     Date  Country  Births
0  1.1.20  England       1
1  1.1.20    Italy       1
2  1.1.20      USA       2
3  2.1.20    Italy       2
4  3.1.20      USA       2
```

Also, the pandas documentation has several examples related to group-by operations : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html.